Changing colors of grouped bars and x-axis numbers in grouped bar chart
My issue is that I wish to alter the colors of the bars in my grouped bar chart, plus the x-axis numbers are not quite what I want. I wish for the bar colors to be "Pots with water" == blue, and "Pots with growth" == "green, and my x-axis to say Pots 1 - 40, not 0 - 39.
enter image description here a grouped bar chart of days each net pot got water, and days each net pot had plant growth.
I feel like I am close, but have not seen this specific issue touched on before. Also, I know it is possible to do in excel but for my project I need to incorporate some code.
My code is pasted below. I was not expecting to see the results I wanted, for I am not sure how to get them. Any help would be great. Is everything imported that I would need? Do I need to add arguments to an existing function or do I need a new function altogether?
Thank you for your help!
###GOT PLANTS AND/OR WATER - GROUPED BAR CHART###

#importing necessary modules
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import numpy as py

#setting up necessary parameters
got_plants_and_water = pd.read_excel(r"C:\Users\terra\OneDrive\Documents\UB_Documents\Classes\2024_Spring_ENVS_490_Capstone\Aeroponic_Project_Conditions_Results_Got_Plants_and_Water.xlsx", 
                                     sheet_name = "Got_Water_or_Plants", 
                                     usecols = ["Pot", "Days with Water", "Days with Growth"])
plants_and_water_df = pd.DataFrame(got_plants_and_water)

#making arrays
Pots = py.array(plants_and_water_df["Pot"])
water_pots = py.array(plants_and_water_df["Days with Water"])
growth_pots = py.array(plants_and_water_df["Days with Growth"])
positions = py.arange(len(Pots))
water_or_growth = py.array([water_pots, growth_pots])

#plotting bars using for loop
width = .4
for i in range(len(water_or_growth)):
    plt.bar(positions + width * i, water_or_growth[i], width)


#customization of axes, labels, add legend, title, etc.
plt.xlabel("Pot Number", color = "navy")
plt.ylabel("Number of Days", color = "navy")
plt.title("Number of Days Pots had Water and/or Growth", 
          fontsize = 15, 
          color = "navy")
plt.yticks(py.arange(0, len(water_pots), step = 4))
plt.xticks(py.arange(start= 0, stop=40, step = 1))
plt.legend( ["Pots with Water", "Pots with Growth"])
plt.show()

